# Analytical solution to $\sqrt{a^2-x^2} + \sqrt{b^2-x^2} = \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \cdot \sqrt{b^2-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can't find beauty analytical solution to such equation :

$$\sqrt{a^2-x^2} + \sqrt{b^2-x^2} = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot\sqrt{b^2-x^2}$$

Assuming $a,\ b \in \mathbb{N},\ a \le b,\ x \in \mathbb{R}$

Is it possible to find a solution for general case?

Comment: What is $N_0$ ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This is similar to solving $x+y=xy$.

Comment: @Vasya: how would you solve $x+y=xy$ ??

Comment: $N_0$ is naturals with zero, i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: @YvesDaoust: a trivial solution is $x=y=0$, It's also easy to see that there is no solution if $0 < x \le 1$. For all other $x > 1$, $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$

Comment: @Vasya: in what way is this useful to the question on hand ? In particular, $x=y=0$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=y$. We have

$$y+\sqrt{b^2-a^2+y^2}=y\sqrt{b^2-a^2+y^2},$$

$$y=(y-1)\sqrt{b^2-a^2+y^2}.$$

Squaring, you will obtain a quartic equation, which doesn't seem to simplify.

Comment: Yes, a good hint, not tried it yet. I've tried to solve quartic -- it looks very ugly, yet :/

Comment: @Uthering: it does.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have $$\dfrac1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}=1$$

WLOG $a^2-x^2=\sin^4t, b^2-x^2=\cos^4t$

$\implies b^2-a^2=\cos2t$

$$4a^2-4x^2=(2\sin^2t)^2=(1+a^2-b^2)^2$$

$$\iff4x^2=?$$

Comment: Looks very nice :) Yet, $a^2-x^2=\sin^4{t}$ states that $a^2-x^2 \in [-1,1]$ and we loose  solutions. If I state that, f.e. $a^2-x^2=r^2*\sin^4{t}$, than again terrible thing appears :/